# odoo from api v8 onchange dosen't work in wizard

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

From new api(v8) onchange dose not work in wizard

Hello expert,

In product form I added onchange (`@api.onchange`) for some field, it works perfectly for normal form view but not for wizard i.e. When I am trying create product form m2o drop-down --> create and edit product new wizard will open then onchange dosen't work.

Comment: please put your code to better understanding?

Comment: Yes, please put your code, but remember that the wizard is another object and you need to put the on_change on that object.